# Press Homebutton return to app /Cordova

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I use ChildBrowser and cordova - newest version. When I open ChildBrowser in my app and press the home button of my iPhone the app is running in the background.

When I click my app again, my last action window of course comes up. In this case ChildBrowser is coming up again. Of course there is an website where user must be authenticated, when I use ChildBrowser. By default the user will get logged out after one day or so because of security.

How can I check first, if the user is still authenticated before ChildBrowser is coming up again when I return to my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is the answer to my question.

RTFD! :)

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#resume